# Restricting access to GeoServer webapp to Localhost in Tomcat?

Tags: geoserver, windows, tomcat, geoserver-manager

I am currently running Tomcat 7 on a Windows Server 2008 machine.  I have GeoServer 4.2.1 installed as a `war`.  What I need to do is restrict access to GeoServer Manager only to Localhost.  As it currently stands you can access the Manager anywhere by going to

```
https://www.mydomain.com/geoserver
```

I would like to only give access to Geoserver Manager by means of

```
https://127.0.0.1/geoserver
```

I have updated by `context.xml` file to limit access to Tomcat Manager via localhost with this:

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"allow="127.0.0.1" deny=""/>
```

Would I do something similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use exactly the same mechanism to limit access to any web application. If the web application doesn't have a context.xml file you can simply create an empty one and add what you need.